# Как запушить один коммит, чтоб не заливалась вся история

Tags: git, bitbucket

Такая ситуация. Проект перенесен на другой удаленный репозиторий. И при выполнении задачи и попытке ее залить, у меня заливается вся история гита. Подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно поступить в данной ситуации.

Comment: А почему залить всю историю - это не правильно?

Comment: Потому что репозиторий уже содержит эту историю в себе

Comment: @РенатКлинджев если репозиторий уже содержит историю - при пуше долъет только разницу

Answer (score 1):

Данная проблема решилась благодаря удаление папки .git и клонирования ее с нового удаленного репозитория.
Спасибо всем, кто принимал участие в обсуждении.

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант можно установить SourceTree - Визуализация и управление репозиториями через простой интерфейс SourceTree. В нем можно выборочно запушить отдельные файлы.